# react Material-UI - Table - TableBody cannot be looped

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an issue with react material-UI's table component.

I wanna create a table where the content is shown dynamically based on the data it receives. So I'm looping through the data, each time creating a new TableBody as the root element. But when I'm looping through the data, it only displays the first (or maybe the last) cycle in the loop.

Here is my code from the render method (the code is vastly simplified):

```
 <Table selectable={ false }>
    <TableHeader displaySelectAll={false} adjustForCheckbox={false}>
       <TableRow>
            <TableHeaderColumn colSpan={3}>{ this.i18n('Filename') }</TableHeaderColumn>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHeader>
        {
          files.map((file, idx) => (
            <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={ false } key={idx}>
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>{ file.name }</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn colSpan={2}><Button variant="flat" data-name='cancel' color="primary">{ this.i18n('Delete') }</Button></TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow />
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn colSpan={3}>
                  <RadioButtonGroup name='caption' />
                    <RadioButton />
                    <RadioButton />
                  </RadioButtonGroup>
                  <Input type='text' />
                </TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
          ))
        }
      </Table>
```

This only outputs one cycle in the in the loop, even though the data contains several loops.

NOTE::: The code works, when I replace the material-UI with a html table, then it works as expected.

Comment: Just tested this, appears to be a bug. Cannot have more than one TableBody.

Comment: @JeffMcCloud thanks for testing it out.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you create a tableBody every item loop, try to set the loop right after < TableBody > tag, because you want to loop < TableRow > not < TableBody >